# How To Call NSLog in Nativescript on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, debugging, nativescript

> Programming Nativescript on a laptop with a terminal only 100x wide
>   looks like this:

https://s3.postimg.org/arqwz0utv/Screen_Shot_2016_08_16_at_11_29_39_PM.png

I don't know about you, but I can't even see what I'm logging from my app...

#### Here's the plan for my `console.log` module I'd like to create:

- Colors based on `log`, `info`, `warn`, `error` with options to help the colorblind (me)
- Customizable options for every user's preference
- Declutter the terminal to actually make sense of what's being logged from the app

#### What I've tried so far:

- tns-core-module `console` - tried a bunch of different things; can't even figure out how iOS logs to the terminal at all
- tns-core-module `trace` - tried calling `trace.write` but unsuccessful
- trying Swift's `print` and `println`

> In my attempt to create a cleaner `console.log`, how do I call `NSLog`
>   inside my Nativescript app?

I have no problem calling `android.util.Log.v` on Android so that part's all set.

Comment: Do you try `console.dump(args)`. This should help you to log objects in the console.

Comment: Well I'm trying to reduce `Aug 17 02:19:37 Robs-MBP sampleGroceries[16999]: CONSOLE LOG file:///app/pages/login/login.component.js:32:20:` clutter so the console is easier to read.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing as you were attempting to do.  Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not access Variadic Objective-C methods in the iOS runtime.
Here is the list of limitations

Limitations
The following members can not be accessed from JavaScript:

- Unions
- Variadic Objective-C methods, function pointers, blocks
- Structs with constant size array members
- Vectors
- Inline functions
- int64_t, uint64_t outside the [-2^53, 2^53] range
- long double, int128_t, uint128_t

Link to documentation section: http://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/ios/Limitations.html

Comment: Thank you! I'm just getting into Objective-C so this is all new to me :D